# trying to create a drop-out stack class which is a subclass of my ArrayStack class

Tags: java, stack

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DropoutStack<T extends ArrayStack> {
private final static int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;

private int top;
private T[] stack;

public DropoutStack()
{
    this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
}


public void push(T element)
{

    stack[top] = element;
    top = (top + 1 % stack.length);
}
```

}

I'm getting the error: constructor DropoutStack in class DropoutStack cannot be applied to given types;

This is the tester here.

```
public class StackTester{
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args){

    DropoutStack stack = new DropoutStack(2);
    stack.push("test1");
    stack.push("test2");
    stack.push("test3");

    System.out.println(stack);
}
```

}

Comment: is that your problem solved..? if this post solves don't forget to mark as accepted..

Answer (score 0):

You have to define one more parametirized constructor as below

```
public DropoutStack(int capacity)
{
    // Do Logic
}
```

Check out [Using this with a Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Comment: now in my tester i'm getting error: method push in class DropoutStack<T> cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: @user3435566: It doesn't compile because you declare that T must be of type ArrayStack, but then you pass a String to the push method...

Comment: @user3435566 You must pass anything of type ArrayStack to push method, String is no way subclass of ArrayStack. So it will not compile

Comment: So what if I want to be able to pass a generic type into the push method?

Comment: Remove extends ArrayStack from your class declaration. like public class DropoutStack<T> {...}